# Unable to create NSUrl from NSString always getting nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsstringencoding

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:
@"http%3A%2F%2Fsupport24hour.com%2Fworkplace2%2Fbuttler%2Fimage.php%3Fwidth%3D534%26height%3D256%26image%3Duploads%2Fdeals%2FdealImage%2Fdeal_1383005121_IGA+Logo.JPG"];

[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

NSURL * url =  [NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: working for other urls

Comment: but not working specially with the above mentioned url

Comment: i am testing this on iOS 7

Comment: Change `http%3A%2F%2F` to `http://`

Comment: why are you using an already percentage escaped string and you percentage escape again? Use the normal one, manipulate the string if you need (replacing "+" wiht " ") and then escape it.

Comment: Manu ! url was encoded and the second line is decoding it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of my colleague faced the same problem , try below line of code . Hope your problem will be resolved

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:
                           @"http%3A%2F%2Fsupport24hour.com%2Fworkplace2%2Fbuttler%2Fimage.php%3Fwidth%3D534%26height%3D256%26image%3Duploads%2Fdeals%2FdealImage%2Fdeal_1383005121_IGA+Logo.JPG"];

string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[[string stringByURLDecode] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSURL * url =  [NSURL URLWithString:string];

NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
```

Where stringByURLDecode is a category method used to decode URL and it goes like this

```
- (NSString *)stringByURLDecode {

NSMutableString *tempStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self];
[tempStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length])];

return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Best of Luck (y)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't yield back a correctly encoded URL: it is: `'http://support24hour.com/workplace2/buttler/image.php?width=534&height=256&image=uploads/deals/dealImage/deal_1383005121_IGA%20Logo.JPG'`, but it should be: `'http://support24hour.com/workplace2/buttler/image.php?width=534&height=256&image=uploads/deals/dealImage/deal_1383005121_IGA+Logo.JPG'`.  Notice the "+" which replaces spaces in a url-encoded parameter string, as defined in the algorithm defined in the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

You must not percent encode the *whole* string. Instead, only the *data octet* in a component must be possibly encoded.

In other words, a URI consists of components and subcomponents which are delimited by certain characters. These characters are called "reserved characters". The separators for the different components must certainly not be included in the percent encoding.

Note that each component of a URL may require a slightly different percent encoding.

See also [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

---

#### Edit:

The general structure of a URL is given below:

```
  URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

The following two examples are straight copied from RFC which show their component parts:

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
      |   _____________________|__
     / \ /                        \
     urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

The "query component" consists of a list of  "key/value" parameters whose key and value is separated by "=", and whose parameters are separated by "&".

The query component is everything after the question mark `'?'` up until a hash character `'#'`.

The following code *encodes* the *name* or the *value* of a parameter. Note that parameters must be separated by a '&', and the name and value must be separated by a '='.

```
static NSString* form_urlencode_rfc3986(NSString* s) {
    CFStringRef charactersToLeaveUnescaped = CFSTR(" ");
    //CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("!$&'()+,/:;=?@~");
    // Modified for urls (excluding '~'):
    CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("!$&'()+,/:;=?@");

    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                             kCFAllocatorDefault,
                             (__bridge CFStringRef)s,
                             charactersToLeaveUnescaped,
                             legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped,
                             kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

Comment: Yes. It should be like `@"http://support24hour.com/workplace ...`. The query component can be encoded as will be shown shortly in the Edit, wait a second.

Comment: if i change  
5121_IGA+Logo.JPG
to
5121_IGALogo.JPG

Comment: i just removed the '+' character above

Comment: Note: unless the "path" and "authority" component consists of unusual characters which are *reserved characters* (which is very, very, unlikely) then you *only* need to percent encode the *value* and *key* of the query component. Once, you separately encoded them, compose a "parameter-string" with a format string like @"%@=%@". Then compose the parameters to the "query-string" separating them with a "&". Then. finally add this (encoded) query string to the url.

Comment: i am experimenting my stuff with your answer...will let you know ASAP..thanks

Comment: altough.. My problem is solved by another answer...but thanks for the wonderfull explanation of encoding urls

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... how about printing out string before you turn it into an NSURL? Does it look as you'd expect it?

Also: replacing "+" with a Space OR do you actually want to remove it?

Comment: printing is same as expected

Comment: second line is for decoding

Comment: ok, but wouldn't "replace + with [Space]" make...

deal_1383005121_IGA[Space]Logo.JPG out of deal_1383005121_IGA+Logo.JPG

?