# Objective-C - CHCSVParser and HTTP Post

Tags: ios, sql, http-post, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to get a CSV file via HTTP Post webservice on a database so that I can parse it. I currently have this code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.x.x.x/xyz.php?cmd=select * from record and datetime>'%@ 00:00:00' and datetime<'%@ 23:59:59' order by id limit 15", startDate, endDate]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }}
    ////////////////////////////
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Data method was called");
    NSString *contentString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    csvParser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:contentString];

    ParserDelegate *parserDelegate = [[ParserDelegate alloc] initParser];
    [csvParser setDelegate: parserDelegate];
    [csvParser parse];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

This is what I get from the debug log

```
 Command string: http://192.x.x.x/xyz.php?cmd=select * from record and datetime>'2003-10-30 08:00:00 +0000 00:00:00' and datetime<'2013-10-29 07:00:00 +0000 23:59:59' order by id limit 15
[615:c07] Connection Successful
[615:c07] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x7561fd0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x71eb1c0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

I'm getting this bad URL. I can access the URL via a web browser (the browser probably does something). Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to percent encode the query:

Your query consists of *one* parameter (key/value):

```
key:   @"cmd"
value: @"select * from record and datetime>'%@ 00:00:00' and datetime<'%@ 23:59:59' order by id limit 15"
```

Keys and values need to be properly encoded before they are composed to a parameter-string.
The parameter string will be composed by the encoded key, a "=" and the encoded value.

The algorithm to encode one key or value can be found here: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm).

Seel also [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

In order to encode a parameter value or parameter key, you can use this helper function, shown in this answer on SO: ([Unable to create NSUrl from NSString always getting nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654911/unable-to-create-nsurl-from-nsstring-always-getting-nil/19655671#19655671))

#### Note:

Usually, a POST request would put the query parameters into the request body. However, the standard does not explicitly forbid this. A POST request *should* work  with a query parameters string in the URL.

Having said this, the probably better approach is to put the query into the body:

You may set the content type of the body to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (in the header) and then use the same encoding algorithm.

So, if you want to try "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":

1. Set the `Content-Type` header of the request to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2. Serialize your query parameter as described above.
3. Get a `NSData` object with UTF-8 encoding from the resulting query string, and set the body of the request with this data.

Alternatively, you may try another content type, e.g. JSON. Whether this is possible or not depends on the capabilities of the server. Honestly, Content type "application/json" would probably the preferred way.

So, if you want to try "application/json":

1. Set the `Content-Type` of the request to "application/json"
2. Serialize your query parameter as a JSON object, e.g:

   `id jsonObject = @{@"cmd": @"select * from ... limit 15"};`

   utilizing `NSJSONSerialization` where you obtain a `NSData` containing JSON in UTF-8.
3. Set the body of the request with this data.

In both approaches, you should also set the `Content-Length` header which is the length of the body data in bytes.

#### Helper function

The following helper function returns an *encoded name string* or an *encoded value string* of a parameter:

```
static NSString* form_urlencode_rfc3986(NSString* s) {
    CFStringRef charactersToLeaveUnescaped = CFSTR(" ");
    //CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("!$&'()+,/:;=?@~");
    // Modified for urls (excluding '~'):
    CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("!$&'()+,/:;=?@");

    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                             kCFAllocatorDefault,
                             (__bridge CFStringRef)s,
                             charactersToLeaveUnescaped,
                             legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped,
                             kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

In order to compose a (encoded) parameter-string, append "=" to the encoded-name, then append the encoded-value.

In order to compose a (encoded) query-string, concatenate all encoded parmeter-strings by separating them with "&".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This definitely sheds some light. When you say that I need to percent encode the string, can I do it something like this?    NSString *encodedString = [commandString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple. Although the *decoding* algorithm may often lead to the same original string, in order to encode properly - even in edge cases, you need to use a helper method or function. Please see the link to the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654911/unable-to-create-nsurl-from-nsstring-always-getting-nil/19655671#19655671). (will also edit the answer)