# ios issue with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Tags: ios

In my app I need to send some parameters to the url, when I am trying with the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding it is not converting correctly. If I am not using this encoding I am getting null(Exception) from the nsurl.Here is me code.

http://www.mycompurl.co?message=xyz&id=____ here I am sending the id 1 or 2 or any number.
when I convert this string to url by using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding I got 
"http://www.mycompurl.co?message=xyz&id=**%E2%80%8B**1" (when I send 1 as parameter). Then I got the 0 data from the Url.

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?message=xyz&id=​%@",Application_URL,bootupdateNew];
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSError* error = nil;

data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

Thank you In advance

Comment: Your code might add extra space in-between = and 1? Please check

Comment: Thank you for reply, there no space added I tested that

Comment: Show your relevent code

Comment: updated my question with code

Comment: What's the type for bootupdateNew?

Comment: it is also a string type

Comment: What does error contain after data1 = ... execution? Is it != nil?

Comment: I didn't get any error, but I need to get some amount of byte data. But here that encoding added some text to my url so it is thought all are id then I didn't get any data. the data value is o bytes. Because I didn't have any file with that id in DB

Comment: Hey, any one help me out Plz

Comment: actually the problem with the NSString, I think. because I printed the url with the help of nslog and that is printed correctly, but I copied that url in browser then it is redirected to another url but not working. Here is the url **http://..........?message=bootloaderupdater&bootloaderupdaterid=​1** and it is redirected to **http://...........?bootloaderupdaterid=1** here but when I copy this url in text edit then it is showing like this **http://......?bootloaderupdaterid=%E2%80%8B1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Basics

A URL is composed of *several* components.

*Each* component has its *own* rule how the component's source string must be encoded, so that this component becomes valid within the URL string.

Applying `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` will *never always* produce a correct URL if the string consists of *more* than one component (and if we assume, we have an unbounded set of source strings - so that the encoded string actually differs from the source string).

It even won't work *always* with a string which represents any single component.

In other words, for what's worth, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` should not be used to try to make a URL out of several components. Even getting the *URL query component* correctly encoded is at least error prone, and when utilizing `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` it still remains wonky. (You may find *correct* implementations on SO, though - and I posted one myself).

But now, just forget about it:

It took awhile for Apple to recognize this failure, and invented `NSURLComponents`. It's available since iOS 7. Take a look! ;)

Comment: you mean, am I need to send url as a return type of the function ?

Comment: I mean, you should take a look at NSURLComponents. Since there is not API help available yet, use this: in Xcode, choose "File" -> "Open Quickly...". Then enter "NSURLComponents". Open the file (NSURL.h) and read the comments in the API regarding NSURLComponents. If you have no idea what "encoding" for a URL means, you should also read [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986).

Comment: Ya, I read this one, but I didn't found any useful solution. Actually in my code I have two url's with different id's the second one working fine, but not the first one which I mentioned in above code

Comment: Hey, can you please check my new comment. I need to complete this task ASAP. Please help me out

Comment: You may read this: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654911/unable-to-create-nsurl-from-nsstring-always-getting-nil/19655671#19655671) and this [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855735/how-to-send-multiple-parameterts-to-php-server-in-http-post/19857449#19857449)

Comment: Thank you for helping, I found that issue with the php